# copyTo isn't working when adding .getDisplayValue()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy display value from cell X to cell Y in a different spreadsheet using `copyTo()`

When I am trying to add `.getDisplayValue()`  to `var = source` I am getting

source.copyTo is not a function
What I am missing ?

My Code:

```
function copyInfo() {
var activeS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet= activeS.getSheetByName("Holding");
var source = sheet.getRange(7,8);

var copySheet = activeS.getSheetByName("Holding");
var pasteSheet = activeS.getSheetByName("Log");

  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,8,1,1);
  source.copyTo(destination);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

solve it with   `source.copyTo(destination, {contentsOnly: true});`